# Can't convert std::wstring to LPCTSTR in case-insensitive std::map

Tags: c++, stl, stdmap

I'm trying to implement a case-insensitive version of `std::map`. Here's what I have so far.

```
struct NOCASECOMPARE_STRUCT
{
    bool operator() (LPCTSTR psz1, LPCTSTR psz2) const
    {
        return _tcsicmp(psz1, psz2) < 0;
    }
};

std::map<std::wstring, int, NOCASECOMPARE_STRUCT> m_IndexLookup;

IColumn* operator[](LPCTSTR pszColumn) const
{
    auto it = m_IndexLookup.find((LPTSTR)pszColumn);
    if (it != m_IndexLookup.end())
        return m_pColumns[it->second];
    ASSERT(FALSE);
    return nullptr;
}
```

The code above produces compile errors. While the hundreds of lines of STL compile errors are virtually impossible to read, Visual Studio does select a more meaningful message to put in the error list.

> 'bool NOCASECOMPARE_STRUCT::operator ()(LPCTSTR,LPCTSTR) const': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const _Kty' to 'LPCTSTR'
>           with
>           [
>               _Kty=std::wstring
>           ]

If I change the compare method's signature to accept `std::wstring` arguments, that fixes the problem but then argument 2 can't be converted. I suppose I can change the signature to one of each but was hoping to make my code more general purpose.

Questions:

1. Why can't a `std::wstring` convert to `LPCTSTR` (I'm using a Unicode build)?
2. Is there a workaround without changing my compare method signature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comparison operator should take two `const std::wstring` objects as input because that is what `std::map` will pass to it.  From that, use the `c_str()` method and do your comparison:

```
struct NOCASECOMPARE_STRUCT
{
    bool operator() (const std::wstring& sz1, const std::wstring& sz2) const
    {
        const wchar* psz1 = sz1.c_str();
        const wchar* psz2 = sz2.c_str();
        return _tcsicmp(psz1, psz2) < 0;
    }
};
```

You could resort to one liners, but doing it this way is easier for debugging.

When searching, pass the argument as a `wstring`:

```
IColumn* operator[](LPCTSTR pszColumn) const
{
    auto it = m_IndexLookup.find(std::wstring(pszColumn));
    ...
```

`LPCTSTR` is basically `const whar*`.  You can't convert a `std::wstring` to a `const wchar*` directly, but you can via `c_str()`.

Comment: As stated in my question, if I change to this it fixes it but then says it cannot convert argument 2. This is because the string I'm passing to find is an `LPCTSTR`. I understand why `LPCTSTR` can't be converted to `std::wstring`, but not the other way around.

Comment: @JonathanWood Because `std::wstring` does not have a conversion operator to `LPCTSTR`, so you have to call `c_str()` explicitly. But `wstring` does have a constructor that accepts an `LPCTSTR` as input (when `LPCTSTR` maps to `const wchar_t*` when `UNICODE` is defined, that is)

Comment: @cup in the code above, `_tcsicmp()` should be `_wcsicmp()` since the input is strictly Unicode. And there is no need to explicitly cast `pszColumn` to `std::wstring` since `m_IndexLookup.find()` takes a `std::wstring` as input and `std::wstring` has a constructor that will accept the `LPCTSTR` as input.

Comment: @JonathanWood I've never understood why `std::string` and `std::wstring` don't have implicit conversion. Microsoft's `CString` class has had it forever, and it works great.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: It makes no sense to me that that `std::wstring` doesn't have a conversion operator to `LPCTSTR`. It owns an `LPCTSTR`. All it has to do is return a pointer to it. This makes zero sense. Having to create and initialize a `std::wstring` object just to pass my `LPCTSTR` to the find method is overhead that is completely unnecessary.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Exactly!

Comment: @JonathanWood implicit conversions can cause subtle and sometimes hard-to-debug issues at runtime. So the standards committee decided against giving `(w)string` implicit conversions to `char*`/`wchar_t*`, opting for explicit conversions instead. Same with the standard containers.

Comment: @JonathanWood "*Having to create and initialize a `std::wstring` object just to pass my `LPCTSTR` to the `find` method is overhead that is completely unnecessary*" - you don't have to construct the `wstring` explicitly, you can construct it implicitly, `find(pszColumn)` will create a temp `wstring` for you. But you still need a `wstring` no matter what, since that is what `find()` takes as input.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: But that's the error this post is about. If I just pass `pszColumn`, then I get the error I posted about.

Comment: @JonathanWood [works fine for me](https://ideone.com/KytQ1f) when `NOCASECOMPARE_STRUCT::operator()` takes `wstring` parameters, as it should since that is what the `std::map` key uses

Comment: @JonathanWood you could always provide 3 different versions of `operator()` that take different combinations of `const std::wstring&` and `LPCWSTR`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Well dang! Now that works for me. I can't see what changed from what I originally posted. Strange.

Comment: @JonathanWood `bool operator() (LPCTSTR psz1, LPCTSTR psz2) const` -> `bool operator() (const wstring &psz1, const wstring &psz2) const`, and `find((LPTSTR)pszColumn)` -> `find(pszColumn)`

Comment: @JonathanWood next time save your changes in git/svn even though there are errors - that way you can always rollback or see what you changed.

Comment: @cup: I tried a bunch of variations. Thought I tried all of them but perhaps I'm mistaken. But I never would've checked each variation in if I had it on Github.

Comment: @JonathanWood don't bother with github - just use git locally.